# function inside ngFor is fired x times

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

i'm having a weird issue on my ionic app. i'm trying to create a modal page where user may enter opening hour of something. there is each day inside my json.

when i try to click the button to add another hour in the day, the function is fired 7 times (one for each day). I don't understand why

Do you have an idea ?

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let day of json.days">
    <ion-list-header>
        {{day.title}}
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-6><ion-datetime displayformat="HH:mm" pickerformat="HH mm" placeholder="00:00" ></ion-datetime></ion-col>
            <ion-col col-6><ion-datetime displayformat="HH:mm" pickerformat="HH mm" placeholder="00:00" ></ion-datetime></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <button ion-button clear (click)="addHours(day.id, $event)">test</button>
</ion-list>




addHours(id,event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    for (let key in this.json.days) {
        console.log(this.json.days[id]);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you saying that `addHours` is called 7 times? Or is it that you `console.log` 7 times when `addHours` is executed?

Comment: Oh my god.... it's okay now... I need some sleep i think. Thank you man

Comment: You are welcome. :-)

Comment: @FriedrichDylan Please remove your question